# Plot a function from other m file

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I'm working on numerical computation methods. I'm new to octave. I download two m files from the internet. Here I just gonna show you the problem-related code, not the whole code.

> From funct.m file:

```
function [ y ] = funct (x)
y=(x*(exp((-x)+3)))-sin((7*x)-4)+(8*x)-20
endfunction
```

I Think there is no problem there. The error occurred when I tried to plot the function in secant.m file. I've tried two kind of plotting functions. `plot()` and `fplot()`

> secant.m file:

1.plot():

```
x=linspace(0,10,20); 
plot(x, funct(x));
```

The error message is *nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x20, op2 is 1x20)*

2.fplot():

```
fplot(funct(x),[0,10],10)
```

The error message is *nonconformant arguments (op1 is 5x1, op2 is 5x1)*

How can I fix this error? I'm familiar with other programming language, especially C-like syntax, so feel free to answer it in technical way.

Comment: try to change `*` with `.*` in declaration of `funct` or `y=zeros(size(x))` and define each `y(ii)` value in `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the element-wise multiplication operator ([`.*`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html)) in your `funct` equation.

```
y = x .* exp(-x + 3) - sin(7*x - 4) + 8*x - 20
```

This is because you want each element of `x` to be multiplied by each element of `exp(-x + 3)`